# javascript alert does not showup on my handy

Tags: javascript, android, html

when I test the following code in a browser like firefox it works perfectly well. When I transform it to an apk via Quick-App and put this apk on my samsung-handy, I will see the button but the alert does not show up.
Are there any settings on the handy that may prevent such popups or what might be the reason that the alert does not showup?
Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_alert()
{
alert("Hello");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="show_alert()" value="Show alert box" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: handy = smartphone? (german English.....)

Comment: yes handy = smartphone